# Python : why result not giving complete floating number: Updated

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am newbie to python.
I have one surprise result after executing following mathematical operation:

```
1.1 + 2.2
```

= `3.3000000000000003`

then 
`4 / (2.0 + 3)` =  should be `0.80000000000000004` as per above operation.

but python return `0.8`.

i am not understanding why this difference is?
[image]

i am using **Python 2.7.6** 
Please see attached image.

i know that if i use `print (1/3.0`) then it will give `3.30`

My question are
1. why all digits of second operation is not displayed but all digit of first one's displayed?

2. how can we compare floating variables those values are dynamic for accurate result?

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: And its not only python, try Java and check the results.

Comment: I recall that Python does do something funky with its dealings with floating point. I can't recall what they call it though. I've retracted my dupe close vote since I think it could be important.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The dupe only partially explains Python's output.

Comment: `1 / 3.0` seriously gives you `3.30`? Interesting Python you have there :)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: That's the *exact* question I was thinking about: "round-tripping" was the term I was trying to recall.

Comment: @JonClements :i cant understand what are you want to say? is my screen are wrong or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Python uses a minimalist `repr` for `float`s when possible. That is, it prints a value that is as precise as necessary to reproduce the exact value of the original `float` if you typed it in directly.

For `1.1 + 2.2`, the imprecision means it doesn't actually produce `3.3` precisely (`1.1 + 2.2 == 3.3` will evaluate to `False`). By contrast, `4 / (2.0 + 3)` is exact enough that `0.8` represents it precisely, (`4 / (2.0 + 3) == 0.8` evaluates to `True`) so it doesn't include a whole bunch of `0`s that aren't required to reproduce the value.

If you want to explicitly print a certain number of places after the decimal, use `str` formatting to specify, e.g.:

```
>>> print('{:.16f}'.format(4 / (2.0 + 3)))
0.8000000000000000
```

If you formatted it with additional digits, you'd see the `4`, but that value is still exactly the same as `0.8`; `0.80000000000000004 == 0.8` evaluates to `True`, so Python avoids the verbosity and just gives you shortest of many equivalent representations.

The [What's new in Python 3.1 docs (scroll to end of linked section, just before "New, Improved and Deprecated Modules")](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes) are a useful explanation for why/when Python 2.7/3.1+ have much shorter `float` `repr`s for some values. Straight from the horse's mouth, so to speak.

Comment: i have updated my question and i dont want to print but  i want to know logic behind it and how to compare these type floating values?